# How to search Lotus documents using VBA

Tags: ms-access, vba, lotus-notes

I need to get 3 specific fields out of a Lotus form and into a static Access table from which I can do more queries (2 of those fields make a primary key so i can join the 3rd with other stuff).  In the pseudo-code below, I've fleshed out a function to do just that, but I can't figure out the details (I don't think I'll ever understand how Lotus works without formal training).  Please help me finish this procedure?

```
Function GetFromLotusDocs() As String
    Dim NtS As New NotesSession
    Dim NtDb As New NotesDatabase
    Dim NtF As New NotesForm
    NtS.Initialize
    Set NtDb = NtS.GetDatabase("MyServer", "MyDB.nsf")
    Set NtF = NtDb.GetForm("MyForm")

    For each document in NtDB
        DoCmd.RunSQL _
        "INSERT INTO TmpTbl ( Fld1,Fld2,Fld3 ) SELECT " & _
        Fld1 & "," & Fld2 & "," & Fld3 & ";"    
    Next document
End Function
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just need to get data out of Notes and into Access, I suggest installing and configuring the Lotus Notes SQL driver.  I've used it many times to pull data into Access, usually to allow me to clean it up before moving it to a SQL or SQL express database.

Here's the link:  http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/lotus/products/notesdomino/notessql/

Comment: That's how I usually pull data out of Lotus. But I don't know which 'table' to link up (the field I'm interested is not in any view, just the document itself). What's the name of the base 'table' in Lotus? "All_Documents"?

Comment: Solved.  I got around the whole code thing by just making a temporary private view and exporting it to a text file.  However, you get the green check since that's your suggestion should be the first thing people try.

Comment: There should be an option to retrieve form data as well, but worst case you can create a view that contains the data you need and then connect it to Access.  Glad you found a workaround!